# Automatically open a file when another file is opened

Tags: bash

In Ubuntu, is it possible to cause one file to open whenever another file is opened (using a shell script, perhaps)?

For example, if I created a file called `stuff.js`, I'd want the file `stuff2.js` to be launched whenever I opened stuff.js from the desktop.

Comment: You mean with one click you want open two files ?

Comment: Yes, that could easily be done using a shell script. But I want one file to automatically open whenever another file is opened - would it be better to simply use a shell script as a launcher for two separate files?

Answer (score 3):

you can create a little script:

```
touch myscript
chmod +x myscript
```

For Gnome

```
echo "gnome-open /path/to/file1" && gnome-open /path/to/file2" > myscript
```

For KDE

```
echo "okular /path/to/file1" && okular /path/to/file2" > myscript
```

Alternative

```
echo "xdg-open /path/to/file1" && xdg-open /path/to/file2" > myscript
```

Note: use only one of the three methods.

Replace your file one's shortcut with this and just double click it, to open the two files simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

Open the second file from the first script. e.g. You have to call the stuff2.js from stuff.js. I think that is the simple way